# Static Ip via Wireless, how to retry if connection drops?

Tags: networking, server, static-ip, wpa-supplicant

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. In order to get Wireless working (static IP) I made only the following change. **This works perfectly, but how can I make this more robust, e.g. continue to scan in case a connection drops? Or** is this already in place with this change.

In other words: does this only try to bring up the network once (at startup), or will this also result in continuous scanning in case the WIFI connection drops?

I added to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto wlp4s0
iface wlp4s0 inet static
address 192.168.1.3
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.3, 8.8.8.8
wpa-ssid <ssid>
wpa-psk <hex password>
```